# JettisonMappedXmlDriver and pretty print with XStream

Tags: java, json, serialization, xstream, jettison

I'm doing serialization with XStream. For XML I use the StaxDriver and for JSON I use JettisonMappedXmlDriver:

```
if (this.format == ISerializer.Format.JSON){
    logger.info("json");
    /* note: JsonHierarchicalStreamDriver can read Json only */
    this.xstream = new XStream(new JettisonMappedXmlDriver());
}
else if (this.format == ISerializer.Format.XML){
    logger.info("xml");
    this.xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
}
```

With XML I get pretty print, with JSON, I never get pretty print:

```
public boolean toStream(Object object, Writer writer){
        if(this.usePrettyPrint == true){
        this.xstream.marshal(object, new PrettyPrintWriter(writer));
    }else{
            this.xstream.toXML(object, writer);
    }
    return true;
}
```

And if I leave my code this way, I will get XML instead of JSON, I had to rewrite my code this way to get JSON, but not pretty-printed:

```
public boolean toStream(Object object, Writer writer){
    if (this.format == ISerializer.Format.JSON){
        this.xstream.toXML(object, writer);
    }
    else{
        if(this.usePrettyPrint == true){
            this.xstream.marshal(object, new PrettyPrintWriter(writer));
        }else{
            this.xstream.toXML(object, writer);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Do you know a way to get pretty printing in JSON with the JettisonMappedXmlDriver?

In the XStream documentation there is no information about it, they even seem to find it OK:

http://x-stream.github.io/json-tutorial.html

but I cannot believe that there is no way to get pretty printed JSON using XStream if you want to be able to serialize and deserialize (JettisonMappedXmlDriver)...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar problem but i used JsonHierarchicalStreamDriver and my solution was

```
this.xstream = new XStream(new JsonHierarchicalStreamDriver () {
    public HierarchicalStreamWriter createWriter(Writer writer) {
        return new JsonWriter(writer, JsonWriter.DROP_ROOT_MODE);
    }
});
```

So Maybe

```
this.xstream = new XStream(new JettisonMappedXmlDriver() {
    public HierarchicalStreamWriter createWriter(Writer writer) {
        return new JsonWriter(writer, JsonWriter.DROP_ROOT_MODE);
    }
});
```

works for you =)

Comment: Hi Wolfi, thank you for your answer, it is not really working and now I'm using GSON...